# An error occurred during the prestashop installation

Tags: prestashop-1.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUb02.png)

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

this is something related to your MySQL database not being fully compatible with Prestashop table creation SQL script.

If you can't overcome this by changing MySQL server , there's a relevant [issue](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/22809) on Prestashop GitHub that should provide you useful detail to fix the issue.

Basically you can try this:

```
install/data/db_structure.sql
```

must be changed with:

```
CREATE TABLE ()...                                                           
...  ) ENGINE=ENGINE_TYPE ROW_TYPE=DYNAMIC ...
```

so that the index size can be adjusted accordingly.